# Error Adding Custom User to Generic Users List

Tags: powershell

I receive the following error when I try to use the .Add() Method to add an instance of a custom user class to generic list of this custom user class.

```
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
At line:8 char:17
+                 $Users.Add($TEST)
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Custom User Class

```
class User {
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Root
    [String]$Username
    [Folder]$Outlook
    [Folder]$AppDataTemp
    [Folder]$Downloads
    [System.Int64]$Size

    User([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Dir){
        $this.DirInfo = $Dir
        $this.Username = $Dir.Name
    }
    [void]GetOutlookDataFiles(){
        $local:Path = "$($this.Root.FullName)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\"
        $local:Query = @('*.ost', '*.nst') 
        $this.Outlook = [Folder]::new($Path)  
        $this.Outlook.GetFiles($Query)
        $this.Outlook.GetSize()
    }
    [void]GetAppDataTemp(){
            $local:Path = "$($this.Root.FullName)\AppData\Local\Temp"
            $local:Query = @("*") 
            $this.AppDataTemp = [Folder]::new($Path)  
            $this.AppDataTemp.GetFiles($Query)
            $this.AppDataTemp.GetSize()
    }
    [void]GetDownloads(){
        $local:Path = "$($this.Root.FullName)\Downloads"
        $local:Query = @("*") 
        $this.AppDataTemp = [Folder]::new($Path)  
        $this.AppDataTemp.GetFiles($Query)
        $this.AppDataTemp.GetSize()
    }
}
```

Code to Cycle through the User Dir and create a new instance of my custom user object then add it to a generic list

```
$Users = [System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]::new()
$DirInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new("$env:SystemDrive\Users\").GetDirectories()
ForEach($Dir in $DirInfo){
    if($Dir.Attributes.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Split(', ') -notcontains 'Hidden'){
        $TEST = [User]::new($Dir)
        $TEST.GetOutlookDataFiles()
        $TEST.GetAppDataTemp()
        $TEST.GetDownloads()
        $Users.Add($TEST)
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the class is in the same file, what happens if you rename the `Users` collection in, e.g., `myUsers` or set the Type, as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]$Users = [System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]::new()`? -- What happens if you move the class to a `.psm1` module file and keep the previous name of the collection?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can reproduce your issue is if you define the `User` class multiple times in the same PowerShell session - that then introduces ambiguity in the type references in these lines:

```
$Users = [System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]::new()
```

and

```
$TEST = [User]::new($Dir)
```

It seems PowerShell uses different heuristics for which type definitions to use for both `[User]` types and selects the *original* type definition for the first line and the *latest* type definition for the second line.

To reproduce, run this in a new PowerShell session:

```
class User { }
$users1 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]::new()
$test1  = [User]::new()
$users1.Add($test1)

class User { }
$users2 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[User]]::new()
$test2  = [User]::new()
$users2.Add($test2)
# MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
```

The immediate solution is to ensure you only define your `User` class *once* in a PowerShell session. The mechanism by which you're defining your class isn't shown in your question (e.g. PowerShell Module? Pasted into an interactive session? etc) so you may need to investigate the root cause yourself...

---

Digging a little deeper we can see:

```
# canary just to prove we can compare types
$test1.GetType() -eq $test1.GetType()
# True

# $test2 is of a different type to $test1
$test2.GetType() -eq $test1.GetType()
# False
```

and

```
# our first generic collection can hold instances our *first* User class
$users1.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] -eq $test1.GetType()
# True

# but our second generic collection *cannot* hold instances our *second* User class
$users2.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] -eq $test2.GetType()
# False

# so what type can it hold? well, instances of our *first* User class
$users2.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] -eq $test1.GetType()
# True
```

So when you try to `Add` an instance of the *second* user type to a collection that can only hold the *first* user type you get the error `MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".` because there is no `Add` method overload that accepts the *second* User type.

The fix is to avoid re-defining a class with the same name within a single session so that PowerShell can only resolve the type `User` to *one* type definition and then there's no ambiguity in the type inferences.

---

In some ways I guess this *could* be considered a bug in PowerShell's type inference in that it should *consistently* select the same type in both lines of code even when there's ambiguity, but it obviously *doesn't* do that at present...

I've reported the problem in [GitHub issue #20893](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20893)

Comment: Okay, so it's a function of testing the same class over and over again in the same session. I should clear my session and try again.